# How to do typescript function chaining?

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

I want to use function chaining in *typescript*.

**Consider a class**

```
export class numbOp(){
  private n;
  constructor(int num){
    this.n = num;
  }

  public add(inc = 1){
    this.n = this.n + inc;
  }

}
```

**How do I use it as (1)**

```
let finalNumber = new numbOp(3);
console.log(finalNumber) // Output: 3
```

**How do I use it as (2)**

```
let finalNumber = new numbOp(3).add();
console.log(finalNumber) // Output: 4
```

**How do I use it as (3)**

```
let finalNumber = new numbOp(3).add().add();
console.log(finalNumber) // Output: 5
```

**How do I use it as (4)**

```
let finalNumber = new numbOp(3).add().add(2).toString();
console.log(finalNumber) // Output: "6"
```

> Please, help me out to achieve this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to return `this` from the functions you want to chain

```
class numbOp {
    private n: number;
    constructor(num: number) {
        this.n = num;
    }

    public add(inc = 1) : this { // annotation not necessary added to address comments
        this.n = this.n + inc;
        return this;
    }
    toString() { 
        return this.n;
    }

}
let finalNumber = new numbOp(3);
console.log(finalNumber + "") // Output: 3
//How do I use it as (2)
let finalNumber2 = new numbOp(3).add();
console.log(finalNumber2 + "") // Output: 4
//How do I use it as (3)
let finalNumber3 = new numbOp(3).add().add();
console.log(finalNumber3 + "") // Output: 5
//How do I use it as (4)
let finalNumber4 = new numbOp(3).add().add(2).toString();
console.log(finalNumber4) // Output: "6"
```

**Edit**

Since the `console.log` part seems to have become more interesting then the chain part in the comments, I'll add the ways to ensure the output in the console is a number:

1. Override `toString` and use string coercion to get the string representation of the object
2. Require a terminator method be called before the display (ie don't forget to call `toString` when you finish the chain)
3. Override `valueOf` and use the unary `+` operator (this will also make you class usable in binary operations

Code for last option:

```
class numbOp {
    private n: number;
    constructor(num: number) {
        this.n = num;
    }

    public add(inc = 1) : this { // annotation not necessary added to address comments
        this.n = this.n + inc;
        return this;
    }
    valueOf() { 
        return this.n;
    }

}
let finalNumber2 = new numbOp(3).add();
console.log(+finalNumber2) // Output: 4
console.log(1 + (+finalNumber2)) // Output: 5
console.log(1+(finalNumber2 as any as number)) // Output: 5
```

Comment: `console.log(finalNumber)` Won't work - that will return an object, not the number (nor a string), pretty sure OP's desired output is impossible without a `toString` call on each

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Exactly my point, this is just an object. Any Way around?

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava Either use a terminating call after the end of each chain to return the number itself, or coerce the result to a string every time

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you tell me what should be the explicit return type of, public add(inc = 1): datatype{}

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava you can let the compiler infer it or use `this` as the return type if you want to be explicit

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava You could override `valueOf` instead of `toString`, that way you can use the unary + operator while logging the object: `console.log(+finalNumber)`. Using `+finalNumber` instead of `finalNumber + ""` is clearer because  you are logging the numeric value of `finalNumber`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir nice idea, i'll add it to the answer as an option

Comment: anyway to do this with promises async await